# Symfony Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have this error when i use :

```
    /**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tag", type="boolean")
 */
private $tag;
```

But i don't understand, in my table i have the field 'tag'.
This error return me a request, and when i run this request in squirrel, all works.

Comment: Try clear metadata caches. `bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

Comment: i have try, but that dosnt work too :/

Comment: you need to share what you really are doing.

Comment: its solved, in my config, my host was bad ...

Comment: nice sounds good :)